# how to exit out of if else condition

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience

I am having few if else condition in my apex class like below,  I need to exit of my if condition without going to the else if, when the condition is met.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String passCase(String caseId){
    List<Case> case_recs = [SELECT id,CS_Team__c,
                       Dedicated_Customer_Service_Rep__c,OwnerId,RecordTypeId,Status,Subject from Case WHERE Id = :caseId];
    String returnString;
    for (Case rec : case_recs)
        {                                   
            //Timed Preg
            if (rec.Subject.contains('time preg')))
            {
                rec.OwnerId = '00G4O000003mG0S';      
            }
            //Dedicated Rep Key Acct
            else if (rec.Dedicated_Customer_Service_Rep__c == userInfo.getUserId() && rec.Customer_Service_Account_Type__c  == 'Key Account')
            {
                rec.OwnerId = '00G0B000003TVkb';
            }                
            //Dedicated Rep
            else if(rec.Dedicated_Customer_Service_Rep__c != null)
            {
               rec.OwnerId = rec.Dedicated_Customer_Service_Rep__c;
            }
           // CS Team
            else if (rec.CS_Team__c != null)
            {
                rec.OwnerId = rec.CS_Team_ID__c;
            }
           //Domestic
            else 
            {
                rec.OwnerId ='00G0B000003TVkg';
            }

            rec.RecordTypeId = '012U0000000QGv4';
            update rec;                
            returnString = 'Updated Sucessfully!';
            return returnString;                  
        }
      return returnString;
 }
```

I tried using `break` but it is not helping here. I am trying to exist from the if else condition and start executing from the code below `rec.RecordTypeId = '012U0000000QGv4';` Am I not handling the if else the right way here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have to worry about this.

In an if/elseif/else chain, *only (and exactly) one* of the branches will be executed for each record you loop over.

Comment: The issue here is even though the condition `rec.Dedicated_Customer_Service_Rep__c == userInfo.getUserId() && rec.Customer_Service_Account_Type__c  == 'Key Account'` is true it executes the  `(rec.Dedicated_Customer_Service_Rep__c != null)` condition. I need to exit out of the branch if the condition is met

Comment: @user81642 If your first condition you provided in your comment were true, then you would not be executing the `else if` branch for `rec.Dedicated_Customer_Service_Rep__c != null` because that condition is only evaluated if the previous two fail. You should use `system.debug()` and/or the Apex Replay Debugger to figure out what data you're actually working with and how it differs from your expectations.